# Show multiple <div> on click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to add some code to a page that keeps adding <div> sections to a page when a link is clicked. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowDiv() {
document.getElementById("show").style.display = "";
}
</script>

<p><a href="#" class="control" onclick="ShowDiv()"; >Add New</a></p>

<div id="show" style="display: none;">
<p>This is the div!</p>
</div>
```

This works great for one <div> but I need it to keep adding down the page when the link is clicked. I t is going to be used to hold a form with an array of ids for posting to PHP.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming in Java? 
Am I missing something obvious? Or are you confused about the two languages? If it's you, then please be a bit more careful with your tags, since appropriately used, they'll get the right experts to your question, but if inappropriately used, they'll just frustrate folks.

Comment: You want to create new divs or just to show existent?

Comment: are you trying to add additional form fields to the form? if you want to keep adding sections just displaying divs is not the correct way to go about this.

Comment: Create new divs. Thank you

Comment: jQuery-- `append()` is all you need!

Answer (score 5):

You can clone original `div` (which will be as template) and append cloned one to the page:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0d2nj5zb/).

HTML:

```
<p>
    <a id="add" href="#" class="control">Add New</a>
</p>

<div id="show" style="display: none;">
    <p>This is the div!</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i = 0;

    $('#add').click(function()
    {
        var newEl = $('#show').clone();
        newEl.attr('id', "show" + i);
        i++;
        newEl.show().appendTo("body");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowDiv() {
    var a = $("#show").clone(true); // clones element
    $(".test").append(a);  // appends to parent
}
</script>

<p><a href="#" class="control" onclick="ShowDiv()"; >Add New</a></p>
<div class="test">  <!-- defines parent for simple selection -->
    <div id="show"> <!-- element to clone -->
        <p>This is the div!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're adding elements to the page with the same id. That is a no-no.